# Hiding a div onmouseout

Tags: javascript, html

Hi guys I was making a javascript function for dismissing or hiding a div Ive search through the internet and found some answers but it does not apply on my code 
Here is my code:

```
<script>
 function Displayout()
 {
    $("#siteicon").mouseout(function () {
    $("#map_tooltip").hide("drop", { direction: "down" }, "slow");
    });
 }
</script>
```

And here is the div that will trigger the function

```
<div id='siteicon' style="background-image:url('src/images/redbutton.png');margin-top:0px;margin-left:-8px;height:10px;width:10px;background-repeat:no-repeat;" onmouseover="displayData();" onmouseout="Displayout();"></div>
```

**UPDATE:**

and here is the id of the div I want to hide

```
<div id='infocontainer'></div>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is happening? What do you expect to happen? What have you tried to do to fix it? Please read [ask] and [mcve] to improve your question and improve the odds of getting a good answer.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use the [.hide](http://api.jqueryui.com/hide/) method from jQuery UI? Are you sure jQuery UI is loaded? If it isn't, it will try to use the default [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) built into jQuery, which expects different parameters.

Comment: @UselessCode I updated my question I hope its clear now :-)

Comment: What is happening currently, what is wrong with it? Does the div you are trying to hide not hide? Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @UselessCode im trying to display div onmouseover like a tooltip then onmouseleave it dismisses or hide the div that acts like a tooltip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is syntax wrong with your [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) method. Try this:

```js
function displayData()
{
    $("#map_tooltip").show("slow");
}

function displayOut()
{
    $("#map_tooltip").hide("slow");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id='siteicon' style="background-color:grey;margin-top:0px;margin-left:-8px;height:20px;width:60px;background-repeat:no-repeat;" onmouseover="displayData();" onmouseout="displayOut();">SiteIcon</div>
<div id='map_tooltip' hidden="true">Should be hidden on mouseout of #siteicon</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameters for hide are wrong, it's giving error "Uncaught TypeError: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function". You can use "slow" to slow up the hiding effect but you can't specify the direction. You order is wrong as well. Please have a look at [`JSFiddle for Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/akej5be9/) and [`api.jquery.com for for hide function`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `onmouseout` since you are using JQuery, and there seems to be a problem in the `hide()` of yours, so try removing the parameter inside.

```js
$('#test').mouseout(function() {
  $(this).hide();
})
```

```css
#test {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background-color:pink}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">content</div>
```